# How to push the footer in MUI at the very bottom and make it stick?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
import * as React from "react";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "@/src/Link";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";

export default function GuestFooter() {
  return (
    <Paper sx={{marginTop: 'calc(10% + 60px)', bottom: 0}} component="footer" square variant="outlined">
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Box
          sx={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            display: "flex",
            my:1
          }}
        >
          <Link href="/">
            <Image priority src="/Logo.svg" width={75} height={30} alt="Logo" />
          </Link>
        </Box>

        <Box
          sx={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            display: "flex",
            mb: 2,
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="caption" color="initial">
            Copyright ©2022. [] Limited
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: position: "fixed",
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,

Answer (score 12):

Just added the position sticky, and set the width to a 100% so it's always sticked to the bottom, using **bottom: 0**.

```
 export default function GuestFooter() {
  return (
    <Paper sx={{marginTop: 'calc(10% + 60px)',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%'
    }} component="footer" square variant="outlined">
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Box
          sx={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            display: "flex",
            my:1
          }}
        >
            <div>
            <Image priority src="/Logo.svg" width={75} height={30} alt="Logo" />
            </div>
        </Box>

        <Box
          sx={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            display: "flex",
            mb: 2,
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="caption" color="initial">
            Copyright ©2022. [] Limited
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

**Changes** *done on the MUI 'Paper' component, which wraps your whole JSX:*

```
position: 'sticky',
bottom: 0
width: '100%',
```

**Final Result**:

```
 <Paper sx={{marginTop: 'calc(10% + 60px)',
position: 'fixed',
bottom: 0,
width: '100%'
}} component="footer" square variant="outlined">
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. However, this `sx={{marginTop: 'calc(10% + 60px)'` doesn't get applied as I actually wanted some breathing space on top.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so i found  the 'cleanest' solution to that.

You can create a Box Component as a direct parent of your Footer Component with the following styles

```
<Box
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      minHeight: '100vh',
    }}
  > 
  <YourFooterComponet/>
</Box>
```

In your component footer use margin top: auto. Something like this:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    borderTop: "1px solid #000",
    marginTop: "auto",
    p: 4,
  }}
  component="footer"
>
 {your-content}
</Box>
```

This aproach guarantees the footer always at the final of the content body page.
I found the solution on this references:

- second example on this link: https://frontendshape.com/post/create-a-footer-in-react-mui-5
- explanation of css styles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pggIVY5eOGM

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your children components (not Footer) with a Box like this:

```
<Box display={"flex"} minHeight={'calc(100vh - FOOTERHEIGHTpx)'}>
{children}
</Box>
```

Or you can add following properties in your individual page components:

`display={"flex"} minHeight={'calc(100vh - FOOTERHEIGHTpx)'}`

Don't forget to replace FOOTERHEIGHT with the actual height of your Footer component.

This works perfectly. With this method you can use standard styling for your footer component without using any additional properties like position and bottom.